# Continuous Random Variables including exponential distribution

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

Let $X$ be an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda=9$. Let $Y$ be the random variable defined by $Y=10e^X$. Compute the probability density function of $Y$: 
what is $f_Y(t)$ (for $t\geq10)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I assume you mean $Y=10e^X$. Please make an effort to compute $P[Y\leq y]$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints to get you started.

The cdf of $Y$ is given by

$$\begin{align*}
F_Y(t)
&=P(Y\leq t)\\\\
&=P(10e^X \leq t)
\end{align*}$$

Can you go from here to get this in terms of the cdf of $X$? That is, $P(X\leq x)$.

Comment: I calculated for a few times but I am not sure whether this is correct:
10e^x <= t
ln10+x <= lnt
x <= lnt-ln10

Comment: Please include your efforts into your original question.

Comment: calculated for a few times but I am not sure whether this is correct:
10e^x <= t
ln10 + x <= lnt
x <= lnt - ln10
Then cdf of X:
e^(-9x)dx | (lny/10 ~ 0) = (-1/9)e^(-9x) | (lny/10 ~ 0) 

Could you tell me what should I do next?

Comment: Please edit this into your original question and use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format it to improve readability.